# iOS AC3 AudioStreamBasicDescription properties aren't filled after calling AudioFileGetProperty method

Tags: ios, mp3, audioqueue

I am calling the AudioFileGetProperty method in order to set properties of AudioStreamBasicDescription object for .ac3 audio file, but as a result all properties are 0.
Here is my code

```
NSString *soundFile= [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sample1AC3.ac3"];
            CFURLRef soundURL = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(kCFAllocatorDefault, (__bridge void*)soundFile, kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, false);
            int err;
            err = AudioFileOpenURL(soundURL, kAudioFileReadPermission, 0, &mAudioFile);
            //  
            AudioStreamBasicDescription audioFormat;
            UInt32 size1 = sizeof(audioFormat);
            //    
            err = AudioFileGetProperty(mAudioFile, kAudioFilePropertyDataFormat, &size1, &audioFormat);
```

It's My log

audioFormat AudioStreamBasicDescription {...}

mSampleRate Float64 0

mFormatID   UInt32  0

mFormatFlags    UInt32  0

mBytesPerPacket UInt32  0

mFramesPerPacket    UInt32  0

mBytesPerFrame  UInt32  0

mChannelsPerFrame   UInt32  0

mBitsPerChannel UInt32  0

mReserved   UInt32  0

The code works for .mp3 fine and I don't understand why it doesn't work for .ac3 format.

Comment: try giving the hint parameter in AudioFileOpenURL, the third param is a hint, give it kAudioFileAC3Type, see if that works

Comment: Thanks Daniel.it works!But after that I am getting err=1718449215 error in following code                                        OSStatus err;
    err = AudioQueueNewOutput(&audioFormat, audioQueueOutputCallback, (__bridge void*)self, NULL, NULL, 0, &mAudioQueue);
    
    NSLog(@"err = %d", err);

Comment: post that code perhaps, so now the NSLogdoes output the correct output?

Comment: if you about NSLog(@"err = %d", err); that Yes, the output is correct.